# DebugVisualizer for UserControl

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging

How to write a debug visualisers for a user control?

The user control has a bitmap property that needs to be displayed in the watch window during debugging. Let me know if this is possible.

-Datte

Comment: A bitmap has very few properties that are interesting.  Size is about it, already easily visible.  If you hope to create a debugger visualizer that actually shows the bitmap then abandon that plan, it ain't going to work.

Comment: @Hans: there is a visualizer on the VS gallery that can do this - http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0954c361-ae31-491b-a503-926032c79a3d

Comment: @adrian - I stand corrected :)

Answer (score 0):

Basic instructions:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379596(v=vs.80).aspx

Here's an example which will also probably assist you as well:

http://imagedebugvisualizer.codeplex.com/

Pretty sure you can't actually make it modify the watch window itself, but when you have a variable there you can select your visualizer and inspect it. You may be able to  get away with just using the example visualizer and throw something like Control.PropertyName in the watch window to view it.